# Effective linq contains with anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, contains, anonymous-types

I have a collection of anonymous objects created like this:

```
var srcCategories = srcSet.Categories.Select(c => new
{
     ApplicationId = c.IsGLobal ? (long?)null : c.App.Id,
     c.Name
});
```

Note that this collection does *not* come from my data context; it's generated from input from an external system. I need to map *both* `ApplicationId` and `Name` with entities in my database. So far this is the only way I've been able to successfully make it work:

```
var trgCategoryIds =
    (from c in core.Domain.Categories.AsEnumerable()
     let ci = new { c.ApplicationId, c.Name }
     where srcCategories.Contains(ci)
     select c.Id)
    .ToArray();
```

But this requires me to pull the entire `Categories` table into memory first. I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this, preferably in a single query. I've tried all of the following options, none of them can be converted to sql:

```
// Removed .AsEnumerable()
var trgCategoryIds =
    (from c in core.Domain.Categories 
     let ci = new { c.ApplicationId, c.Name }
     where srcCategories.Contains(ci)
     select c.Id)
     .ToArray();

// Use .Any() instead of .Contains()
var trgCategoryIds =
    (from c in core.Domain.Categories
     where srcCategories.Any(s => s.ApplicationId == c.ApplicationId && s.Name == s.Name)
     select c.Id)
    .ToArray();

// Use Tuples instead of anon types
var srcCategories = srcSet.Categories.Select(c => Tuple.Create(...));
var trgCategoryIds =
    (from c in core.Domain.Categories
     let ci = Tuple.Create(c.ApplicationId, c.Name)
     where srcCategories.Contains(ci)
     select c.Id)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Are these two different databases, or one database?  Are both `Categories` collections coming from the same `DataContext`?

Comment: @Servy No, the `srcCategories` is derived from input from an external system - specifically, a web service exposes a list of categories, which are then filtered down based on command-line parameters.

Comment: Well if the two IQueryables come from different sources how would you ever expect to avoid pulling one of the two data sets into memory?  The two almost certainly aren't going to know how to talk to each other.

Comment: @Servy - The way I read it, the first data source is effectively irrelevant - it becomes an object which is a `string`/`long` pair before we get to the second database.  So it's just comparing a list of in-memory objects to the database.

Comment: The `.Contains` method translates to the sql `IN` operator. To match to columns in sql you have to create and populate table variable, and join against that. That's essentially what I'd like to do, unless there is a better alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do isn't really possible, because there's no easy SQL for it in the first place.  Effectively, you want:

```
select * from Catagories where (ApplicationID = 1 and Name = "Foo") 
                            or (ApplicationID = 2 and Name = "Bar") 
                            or (ApplicationID = 2345 and Name = "Fizbuzz")
                            or ...
```

Entity Framework, to the best of my knowledge, can't create that type of query automatically.  It can handle a single test by converting `Contains()` to `IN (...)`, but there's no simple SQL for an anded `IN` when you can't `join`.  However, you can use the [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) library to construct this type of `OR` query.  The second example on the page should be just what you need.

Adapted for your usage:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Category>();

  foreach (var cat in srcCategories)
  {
    var temp = cat;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.ApplicationId == temp.ApplicationId && p.Name == temp.Name);
  }
  return core.Domain.Categories.AsExpandable().Where (predicate);
}
```

Comment: +1 This looks promising, but I get: "*Invoke cannot be called recursively - try using a temporary variable.*"

Comment: Nevermind, I had accidentally typed `predicate.Name == temp.Name` It works!

Answer (score 1):

If the two `Categories` collections come from different database contexts then there is no way to get around pulling one of the two into memory.

If they share a database context then what you are trying to do is to simply join the two tables:

```
var query =
    from domainCat in srcCategories
    join sourceCat in srcSet.Categories
    on new { domainCat.ApplicationId, domainCat.Name } equals
        new { sourceCat.ApplicationId, sourceCat.Name }
    select sourceCat.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

what about adaptating the following code, with ks as the formatted categories (Id + "-" + Name).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;

namespace testef {
    //Model
    public class CObj {
        public CObj() {
        }
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public String SomeCol { get; set; }
    }

    //Configuration for CObj
    public class CObjConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CObj> {
        public CObjConfiguration() {
            HasKey(x => x.Id);
        }
    }

    public class TestEFContext : DbContext {
        public IDbSet<CObj> objects { get; set; }

        public TestEFContext(String cs)
            : base(cs) {
            Database.SetInitializer<TestEFContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TestEFContext>());
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CObjConfiguration());
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(String[] args) {
            String cs = @"Data Source=ALIASTVALK;Initial Catalog=TestEF;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True";                

            using (TestEFContext c = new TestEFContext(cs)) {
                c.objects.Add(new CObj { Id = 1, SomeCol = "c"});
                c.SaveChanges();
            }

            IEnumerable<String> ks = new List<String> { String.Format("{0,10}-c", 1) };
            foreach (var k in ks) {
                Console.WriteLine(k);
            }

            using (TestEFContext c = new TestEFContext(cs)) {
                var vs = from o in c.objects
                         where ks.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((Decimal?)o.Id, 10) + "-" + o.SomeCol)
                         select o;

                foreach (var v in vs) {
                    Console.WriteLine(v.Id);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var trgCategoryIds =
    (from c in core.Domain.Categories.AsEnumerable()
     where sourceCategories.Any(sc=> sc.ApplicationId == c.ApplicationId 
                     && sc.Name == c.Name)
     select c.Id)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I've tried that already. It doesn't translate into sql, even if you take of the `.AsEnumerable()`.